# should a moderator be free to use his power to promote his own view?

Tags: discussion

how moderators should be moderated.

as an example a moderator who edits words of Wahhabi to Sunni without any notification is not abusing his powers? there are many sects of sunni which are not wahhabi and this action is in fact not respecting to other views and hijacking the site in favor of a specific view.

Comment: Where did this happen?

Comment: @Ansari here: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2534/what-is-the-justification-of-salafi-schoars-for-destroying-shrine-of-imam-sadiq you can check edits. maybe other cases happened but I do not know them because no notification is sent and I saw two cases here accidentally.

Answer (score 9):

As Ansari has kindly pointed out, Abdullah took a course of action many users can do, which is to submit a suggested edit. *All* users on our sites are moderators, through flagging, editing, commenting, and even answering better than previous answers.

As for the second, my research has indicated to me two things. First, this is not a term these users would choose for themselves. For example, I could refer to a man as `a man`, `male`, or I could refer to him as `Y chromosome`. While all three are *technically* correct, many men of my acquaintance would *genuinely dislike* if I referred to them as `Y chromosome` in my day-to-day conversation. In the same vein, while the term *wahhabi* may not be incorrect -- and may even be technically correct for a number of people who follow this path -- it is not one they like. Part of respecting others means respecting their wishes with respect to labels. You are Ahmadi and not `User67` (though both are technically correct), so I respect you by calling you by the display name you choose for yourself: `Ahmadi`.

Second, you are correct. There are many teachings and subgroups within Sunni Islam. As such, I suggest you say, instead of *wahhabism*, perhaps *the followers of the teaching of Muhammaad ibn Abd al-Wahhab*, though longer, would prove less incendiary overall. You could even choose to be more vague: "Some schools of Sunni scholarship believe..." would serve your purpose without explicitly calling out any single group of people in an offensive way.

Comment: my point is this action was a biased action (perhaps vandalism) but because the majority of this site are pro wahhabism no action is taken but similar action from a shia user can lead to suspend.many political reasons behind trying to hide this name and instead using name sunni.it is not only matter of offense as claimed. this word is not insult in fact. but when people research about this and read history of this movement full of killing and terror will hate it and this is what they do not want to people know about this movement and so hide its real name. offense is only excuse.

Comment: @Ahmadi In my experience, *every single group of people* on this planet have a history of, as you put it, "killing and terror," whether of their own or of their enemies. This is something that nearly every race, creed, class, color, religion, sect, nationality, and so forth can claim as part of their history. Constantly pointing this out in your answers -- which is often not topical to the question -- makes people feel like they are being blamed for actions far beyond them personally. It isn't *nice*. You have been linked to our niceness policy before. Please begin adhering to it.

Comment: can you mention some terrors in history of shia Muslims? I ask you compare history of shia with history of wahhabism. all Imams of shia were being killed or poisoned. look at death column here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imamah_%28Shi%27a_doctrine%29 and then look here: http://www.terrorism-illuminati.com/wahhabis shia have been always victim of terror. it is not beyond them. calling shia Mushriks and who are worse than idol worshipers and encouraging killing shia can be seen very much in books of their scholars. what I say is fact based on their own books. I can show evidence.

Comment: This site is ***not*** a place to play the "which sect of Islam has acted worse over the course of history" -- if that's the conversation you would like to have, perhaps other spaces would serve you better. We are here to explore and learn about *all sides* of Islam. Constantly bringing up the worst of a single group's history isn't constructive or valuable. I'm going to be direct: this kind of language does not make this site better. Insisting that a group of people are terrorists does not make this site better. These kinds of actions imply you have an agenda beyond learning and teaching.

Comment: I know this site is QA and I do not want bring its history here. I only explained it to you know why they try to hide this word and instead call themselves sunni or Muslim. "all sides of Islam" one side is wahhabism and this site should allow to all learn about it. I said terror for you only to know reason of hiding this word. my problem is why a user should the right to ask a word that in fact is not insult be censored in this site?

Comment: `my problem is why a user should the right to ask a word that in fact is not insult be censored in this site?` Because that word is (a) not a self-utilized term, and (b) is protested. There are other, more polite/specific terms you could use to express your feelings about these teachings. A user is allowed to protest because *he or she finds that word offensive in some way*. We are a *community* of people here; every voice is valid, and every complaint is heard. We have heard enough from protesters/research to feel that this word isn't constructive or descriptive. It's not censorship to ask.

Answer (score 5):

Abdullah is not a moderator of this website. He suggested an edit and someone accepted it. You are free to roll it back.

The title of your question is incendiary and accusatory, given that no moderator did what you accuse them of.

In any case, you are aware that he and other users of this website don't think that is an appropriate term. Your refusal to understand that is simply baffling. Maybe you can't understand why it is offensive or incorrect to use that term (just because Wikipedia has a page on it, and some sects use the term doesn't mean it is correct), but that doesn't mean it's OK to use it when other people disagree with its usage. This will be my final word. If you want to stay here, play nice and respect others as you wish they would respect you.

Comment: yes it was my mistake that I taught he is moderator. but this question still remains for other cases. about word wahhabi why disagreement of a users should be considered when his claim for this word being insult is not true. me also disagree banning this word. why his opinion is higher than me? this word is only a name to refer to a movement in saudi arabia and not an insult. banning this word makes your site out of multi view and makes it wahhabi-fiendly and anti shia site. not some sects but near all sects even scholars in saudi arabia and even Najd use it.